# Repeat blocks of columns and row N times based of N number of Columns in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am currently working in Google sheet and would like to create transpose specific columns and repeat on all rows in the table, For example
| ID | Another header | Desc| Item1 |Item2| Item3|Item4| Item5 |
| -------- | -------------- |-------- | -------------- |-------- | -------------- |-------- | -------------- |
|1|AA|BBB|0|0|0|0|0 |
|2|BB|CCC|0|1|0|0|0 |

I would like to get a result as

| ID | Another header | Desc | Item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | BBB | Item1 |
| 1 | AA | BBB | Item2 |
| 1 | AA | BBB | Item3 |
| 1 | AA | BBB | Item4 |
| 2 | BB | CCC | Item1 |
| 2 | BB | CCC | Item2 |
| 2 | BB | CCC | Item3 |
| 2 | BB | CCC | Item4 |

I tried using Lamba function `LAMBDA(x, y, REDUCE(x, SEQUENCE(y-1), LAMBDA(a, b, IF(b, {a; x})))) (range, 4)` but this only helped me to replicated the rows. I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting for the input table got a bit mangled but I think I was able to determine the layout. If your input table begins at A1 in the sheet you can try the following to generate the desired output:

```
={{A1:C1,"Item"};arrayformula(split(tocol(A2:A3&"|"&B2:B3&"|"&C2:C3&"|"&D1:H1),"|"))}
```